# C++ namespace and const variable

Tags: c++

*I compile those files as single program with Visual studio 2019 in win10*

My project have just two source files:

/**** a.cpp  ****/

```
namespace pers{
    const int LEN = 5;
}
```

/**** b.cpp  ****/

```
namespace pers {
    const int LEN = 5;
}

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

It can be compiled successfully.But I dont konw why? I defined `LEN` twice!!

so, I delete the `const` :

/**** a.cpp  ****/

```
namespace pers{
    int LEN = 5;
}
```

/**** b.cpp  ****/

```
namespace pers {
    int LEN = 5;
}

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Now it doesn't work!
So, my question is what happend? `const` variable in diffierent source files can be defined twice or more (means NO multi-definition error) .

Meanwhile, compiler will throw "multi-definition error" if do this:

```
namespace pers {
    const int LEN = 5;
    const int LEN = 5; // multi-definition error

    const int LEN2 = 10;
}
namespace pers {
    const int LEN2 = 10; // multi-definition error
}


int main() {
    const int a = 10;
    const int a = 10; // multi-definition error

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: whats your question? How do you compile the two?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [extern const in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661146/extern-const-in-c)

Comment: You are violating the one definition rule.

Comment: Those should compile.  They won't link, because there are two separate strong linkage **definitions** with the same name.

Comment: in my opinion this should work, const it doesn't means in this situation

Comment: @Eriss69 -- `const` does matter. Unfortunately, this question got closed while I was writing an answer explaining the difference.

Comment: @Eljay -- the C++ standard doesn't talk about "strong linkage definitions". The first pair is okay because both definitions are `static`; the second pair is not okay because they aren't.

Comment: @PeteBecker • the second snippet claimed "it can't be compiled".  But the OP neglected to mention how it was compiled, on what platform, and with which compiler.  The implementation details aside as to the specific "it can't be compiled" encountered; I concur, you are correct.  That is the upstream problem that the linker (assumably) is running afoul of.

Comment: @Eljay -- it doesn't matter what platform or what compiler; the second example is not valid C++. A compiler that accepts it does not conform to the language definition.

Comment: @PeteBecker • The second example is valid C++, as long as those two CPP files are part of different programs.

Comment: @Eljay -- that is, indeed, true. Do you **really** think that's what was intended?

Comment: @PeteBecker • Without knowing how it was compiled, on what platform, with which compiler, and the intent of the OP, I don't know.  We have a dearth of information, and the OP doesn't seem to be interested in their question.  Maybe the OP is making new programs, but compiling all the source together, `g++ *.cpp` (which has been an issue some new programmers have asked on SO before).

Comment: @Eljay -- seriously? Do you worry that the fact that I use the name `LEN` as a global in my code might invalidate your use of the name `LEN` as a global in your code? Do you think that **anybody** does?

Comment: @PeteBecker • Thank you for the warning, I'll avoid using `LEN` in my code so our code doesn't collide.

Comment: Thanks for Eljay and Pete Becker and all ! 

I have added some descriptions for my code. I am new hand for c++. those code worte when I read 《C++ primer plus》5th,  so, they are not for any PROJECT (such as win12), just for learning :)

Thank all again. I have more confidence to learn C++ well !

Comment: the same question's address：https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72371532/why-no-multi-definition-error-in-diffierent-file-if-define-const-variable-repeat

Answer (score 9):

Let's see on case by case basis what is happening:

##### Case 1

Here we consider:

**a.cpp**

```
namespace pers{
    const int LEN = 5; //this LEN has internal linkage and is different from the LEN defined in b.cpp
}
```

**b.cpp**

```
namespace pers {
    const int LEN = 5; //this LEN has internal linkage and is different from the LEN defined in a.cpp
}

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

> It can be compiled successfully.But I dont know why?

This is because `LEN` has **internal linkage** meaning its use is limited to a single translation unit and so the `LEN` in a.cpp and b.cpp are **not the same**. This can be see from [basic.link](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.link#3) which states:

> A name having namespace scope **has internal linkage if** it is the name of
>
> - a non-inline variable of non-volatile const-qualified type that is neither explicitly declared extern nor previously declared to have external linkage; or

And also,

> When a name has internal linkage, the **entity it denotes can be referred to by names from other scopes in the same translation unit**.

(emphasis mine)

This means the `LEN` In `a.cpp` and the `LEN` in `b.cpp` are **distinct from each other** and so there is no multiple definition error.

---

> I defined LEN twice!!

As explained above, you're not defining the same `LEN` twice. They are different from each other because they have a namespace scope and are `const` qualified.

##### Case 2

Here we consider:

**a.cpp**

```
namespace pers{
    int LEN = 5; //this LEN has external linkage and is the same a the LEN in b.cpp
}
```

**b.cpp**

```
namespace pers {
    int LEN = 5; //this LEN has external linkage and is the same LEN as in a.cpp
}

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

In this case, `LEN` has **external linkage** meaning both the `LEN` in a.cpp and b.cpp are the same and since you're defining the same name twice, you're violating ODR.

##### Case 3

Here we consider:

```
namespace pers {
    const int LEN = 5; //OK, define `LEN` with internal linkage for the first time 
    const int LEN = 5; // error because you're defining the same LEN with internal linkage for the second time in the same TU

    const int LEN2 = 10;
}



int main() {
    const int a = 10;  //define a for the first time in this TU
    const int a = 10; // error because you're defining the same a for the second time in the same TU

    return 0;
}
```

In this case 3, you're definining the same `LEN` twice and hence getting the mentioned error. We cannot define any entity more than once in the same translation unit.

Comment: thanks. I read the "basic.link" content, and know that  `const`  means `static` implicitly. I have learned this rule, but forget it, maybe namespace confuse me. Thanks again.

Comment: @achange Yes, `const` in your example means implicitly static. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70523572/12002570) where i explained the same. You're welcome.

Comment: See also here about internal linkage https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration it also lists the exception *non-volatile non-template non-inline non-exported const-qualified variables (including constexpr) [at namespace scope] that aren't declared extern and aren't previously declared to have external linkage [have internal linkage]*

Comment: @achange I think, for linking step it's enough to think of namespaces as of an addition to the names of symbols. Oh, to add to that,, try remove the name of namespace and see how that works.