# Why no multi-definition error in diffierent file if define const variable repeatly in same namsepace?

Tags: c++

*I compile those code with Visual studio 2019 in win10*

My project have just two source files:

```
/**** a.cpp  ****/

namespace pers{
    const int LEN = 5;
}
```

```
/**** b.cpp  ****/

namespace pers {
    const int LEN = 5;
}

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

It can be compiled successfully.But I dont konw why? I defined `LEN` twice!!

so, I delete the `const` :

```
/**** a.cpp  ****/

namespace pers{
    int LEN = 5;
}
```

```
/**** b.cpp  ****/

namespace pers {
    int LEN = 5;
}

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Now it doesn't work!

So, my question is what happend? `const` variable in diffierent source files can be defined twice or more (means NO multi-definition error) .

Meanwhile, compiler will throw "multi-definition error" obviously if do this:

```
// those code in same cpp file.

namespace pers {
    const int LEN = 5;
    const int LEN = 5; // multi-definition error

    const int LEN2 = 10;
}
namespace pers {
    const int LEN2 = 10; // multi-definition error
}


int main() {
    const int a = 10;
    const int a = 10; // multi-definition error

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please, show how do you include code from the `a.cpp` into the `b.cpp`. My guess is that you do not have a header file for the namespace's interface which you include in files where the namespace is going to be used.

Comment: @rawrex No header file,  I just try your advice of adding a header file "a.h" as
```
#pragma once
namespace pers {
 const int LEN = 10;
}
```
then, I include "a.h" in "main.cpp" and print pers::LEN, it will always be 10. Code of a.cpp and b.cpp have no influence, but compile successfully.