# How to create an own struct and constants for this struct?

Tags: objective-c, struct, components, constants, limit

I want to create a struct which is like a CGPoint, but with 3 coordinates instead of 2.

I create it in the following way:

```
typedef struct {CGFloat x;CGFloat y;CGFloat z;} CG3Vector;

CG_INLINE CG3Vector CG3VectorMake(CGFloat x, CGFloat y, CGFloat z)
{
  CG3Vector p; p.x = x; p.y = y; p.z = z; return p;
}
```

It works fine. But I now want to improve this struct so that it has the constants like for CGPoint: `CGPointZero`

Also what is the way to introduce the limits for particular components of the struct, like it is for the CGSize, where components are never lower than 0?

Thanks.

Comment: Not for a floating point, but have you heard of unsigned types?

Comment: Don't use the `CG` prefix on your own types; it belongs to Core Graphics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create constants like this:

```
const CG3Vector CG3VectorZero = { 0, 0, 0 };
```

If you want limits, I suppose you can do some checking like this:

```
CG_INLINE CG3Vector CG3VectorMake(CGFloat x, CGFloat y, CGFloat z)
{
    // normalize the values
    x = fmod(x, 360);
    y = fmod(y, 360);
    z = fmod(z, 360);

    x = (x < 0) ? 360 + x : x;
    y = (y < 0) ? 360 + y : y;
    z = (z < 0) ? 360 + z : z;

    return (CG3Vector) { x, y, z };
}
```

Comment: Probably worthwhile to put `const` on the zero struct.

Comment: Thanks, sounds really logical. Don't understand why I haven't come up with this idea myself. Actually I can put any code between curly brackets, right? For example changing to some default value if it exceeds the limit. But I have another question then. If I want a struct representing a vector through 3 angles in degrees that means  x=(0;360), I can put the transformation of the angle value to a new one inside the limit. But how to do it for a setter of a single component like in this example:

    CG3Vector a=CG3VectorMake(120,70,80);
    a.z=-20; //Should be transformed to 360-20=340

Comment: Thanks. But the line const CG3Vector CG3VectorZero = { 0, 0, 0 }; doesn't work. I get the linker error when compiling. I think that some different syntax must be used for this purpose.

Comment: and also the limiting method works when creating the CG3Vector variable, but it doesn't apply any limit when setting only one component explicitly: vector.z=-20; Then -20 stays -20, not 340.

Comment: @BartoNaz that is a limitation of C-structs, what you are looking for is a C++ struct, or an Objective-C object. As far as the CGVectorZero is concerned, you may want to look into extern variables, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190919/mixing-extern-and-const