# extern const char* const SOME_CONSTANT giving me linker errors

Tags: c++, linker, constants, extern

I want to provide a string constant in an API like so:

```
extern const char* const SOME_CONSTANT;
```

But if I define it in my static library source file as

```
const char* const SOME_CONSTANT = "test";
```

I'm getting linker errors when linking against that library and using SOME_CONSTANT:

> Error 1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "char const * const SOME_CONSTANT" (?SOME_CONSTANT@@3QBDB)

Removing the pointer const-ness (second const keyword) from both the `extern const char* const` declaration and the definition makes it work. How can I export it **with** pointer const-ness?

Comment: well, looks like it should be okay http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190919/mixing-extern-and-const

Comment: Seeing as you've tagged it C++, shouldn't a "string constant" actually be `const std::string` in the first place?

Comment: Also, is the `extern` declaration visible in the source file defining the constant?

Comment: @Angew Why would it? `const char *` is the C "string" type and it's perfectly valid to use it in C++.

Comment: maybe you haven't included API's header in library source?

Comment: @H2CO3 It is perfectly valid, but it's usually more trouble than it's worth. `operator+`, copoying and template argument deduction come to mind.

Comment: @Angew: Even so, I wouldn't expose anything STL-related in a public header because other developers may use a different, not binary-compatible std::string implementation.

Comment: @AndiDog Good point. I take my comment back (but leave it here for future readers).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem could be that the `extern` declaration is not visible in the source file defining the constant. Try repeating the declaration above the definition, like this:

```
extern const char* const SOME_CONSTANT;  //make sure name has external linkage
const char* const SOME_CONSTANT = "test";  //define the constant
```

Comment: That works. I was just wondering how the linker knows it shouldn't strip my symbol... and then I saw your answer and facepalmed :D Of course I have to enforce extern linkage.

Comment: @AndiDog Note that this is the same as just adding `extern` to the definition. As the other answer suggests, `const` in C++ implies `static`. So you need to counteract that and explicitly say `extern` in your definition too.

Comment: "`const` in C++ implies `static`... This seems like an arbitrary hack in C++ specification. Micro optimization for lazy people!!!

Comment: instead of repeating the declaration, which is contrary to the **DRY** (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle, either (A) include your header file in the implementation, or (B) add the keyword `extern` only. Well, as suggested in my answer. I didn't suggest the code repetition, because it serves no useful purpose: it's very ungood.

Answer (score 9):

most probably you forgot to include your header in your implementation file

anyway, add the keyword `extern` to the definition

without an `extern` declaration it has internal linkage and is thus not visible to the linker

Comment: This seems true (tested with recent `gcc` in Linux), +1 for you. Why is that so ? What is the rational here? To make sure that header file declaration and definition match? Any link to explanation for this perplexing behavior?

Comment: re the rationale, why non-`extern` constants have internal linkage in C++, i think it has to do with avoiding needless name collisions and One Definition Rule clashes for linking. C99 has a feature that's *like* it but not exactly the same rules (i'm not sure of the details). essentially it means that you can more freely declare *and define* constants in header files. You may consider moving your constant definition to the header file, and then simply omit the `extern`. You could then add a `static` for good measure, but it's not required: that's what it's all about.

Comment: Like you mention, there is always the well known possibility of defining `static const char * const SOME_CONSTANT = "test";` in the header file. Or we could place the definition in anonymous name space in the header... This still seems to me like a stupid hack that just adds needless complexity to the language definition!!! Maybe it is was considered more readable for header files not to be cluttered with `static` or anonymous namespace embraces.

Comment: @FooF: well, there are some subtleties for arrays and references... ;-)

Comment: I am morbidly curious (it is quite a while since I programmed in C++)... Any links or explanations about the subtleties?

Comment: @FooF: oh, the issue is that a reference or an array can't be `const` in itself. i'm sorry i don't have at hand any discussion of it. but you may possibly google it successfully or use the SO search facility, and anyway, a bit of experimentation can be enlightening. just to be clear, i'm not entirely sure about the status for arrays. it's perhaps worth an SO question... :-)

Answer (score 0):

The solution of the accepted answer can be done in a single step.

You may add the `extern` specifier to the contants' definition.

```
extern const char* const SOME_CONSTANT = "test";
```

Comment: compiler will complain!

Comment: Have not checked against the standard. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/2190981/9437799