# extern const char* const pointer or extern const char array[] cause link error

Tags: c++, c, ld

here is code:

file1.cc

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char *pointerString = "pointerString";
const char arrayString[] = "arrayString";
const char* const constpointerString = "constpointerString";

extern void printString();

int main(void)
{
    printString();
    return 0;
}
```

file2.cc

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern const char *pointerString;
extern const char arrayString[];
extern const char* const constpointerString;

void printString()
{
    printf("pointerString: %s\n", pointerString);
    printf("arrayString: %s\n", arrayString);
    printf("constpointerString: %s\n", constpointerString);
}
```

complite command: g++ file1.cc file2.cc -o out
error link:

```
/tmp/cczatCe9.o: In function `printString()':
file2.cc:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `arrayString'
file2.cc:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to `constpointerString'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

g++ version: 4.6.3(Unbuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)

anyone can help??

Comment: `const` object has internal linkage, so the variables are not visible outside.

Comment: thinks anyway, i get answer from `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977058/extern-const-char-const-some-constant-giving-me-linker-errors`

Answer (score 2):

Put your extern declarations in a header file, and include it in
both source files.  What's happening is that in `file1.cc`,
`arrayString` and `constpointerString` have internal linkage
(because that is the default for `const` objects), and so can't
be seen from other translation units.

Alternatively, of course, you can define them:

```
extern char const arrayString[] = "arrayString";
extern char const* const constpointerString = "constpointerString";
```

But in general, it is better to use the header.