# Behaviour of extern const char* in C++

Tags: c++, string, linker, constants, extern

In the following example:

file1.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern const char* szVers;
extern const int iTest;
extern const char cText[];

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    printf( "Result = %s - %d - %c\n", szVers, iTest, cText[0] );
    return ( 0 );
}
```

file2.c

```
const char* szVers = "Version 1.0";
const int iTest = 6;
const char cText[] = "ABCD";
```

When I compile the sources, I got the following errors:

```
$ g++ -o test file1.c file2.c
/tmp/cctVd57Y.o: In function `main':
file1.c:(.text+0x12): undefined reference to `cText'
file1.c:(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `iTest'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I know that in C++ *const* implies internal linkage, but why there is no an undefined reference error to szVers  ?

Comment: it may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977058/extern-const-char-const-some-constant-giving-me-linker-errors

Comment: @HoàngĐăng: Literally the opposite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your compiler. With GCC 7.1.0 I can reproduce what you get, but with the newer version I get an error for all three variables:

[image]