# Build C application by C++ compiler

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++, undefined-reference

I have an application, which is written on C. A new functionality I need to add in C++. I build C application with GCC.
To add new functionality:

1. To build an existing application with G++.
2. Add new functionality.

When I tried to do (1.), I met following problem:
In file dev_table.c defined array:

`const type_name devices[] = {...};`

in file stm.c I export this array by:

`extern const type_name devices[];`

And when I assign

`stm->dev = devices;`

linker fail.

If I build the same code by GCC, everything is OK and working well, but with G++ it fails.

If I remove `const` from both places(`dev_table.c` and `stm.c`), it is also working well, so the problem is resolved, **but** I do not understand what is the reason.

Comment: what was the error you were getting earlier?

Comment: What is your command line when you build with `g++`, and what is the output?

Comment: You cannot assign arrays in C++.  IDK if you can in C but you can't in C++.  If you need that I suggest you look into using a [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)

Comment: Compile C source with `gcc`, C++ source with `g++` and link with `g++`.

Comment: In C headers use `#ifdef __cplusplus` directives to add `extern "C"` blocks only for C++ complier.

Comment: at deceleration and extern places keep it a pointer not array, at the time of assign array will decay to pointer.  If the array is fixed size it might work but in case of unknown array size it won't work.

Comment: NathanOliver: If I cannot assign arrays, why it works, when I remove `const`.

Comment: "*linker fail[s]*" telling you exactly what?

Comment: When linker fails, ` undefined reference to `devices'`

Comment: I s`stm->dev` declared `const`?

Comment: Yes. But `stm->dev` is pointer.

Comment: You should keep using a C compiler to build the C code.  You can write new code in C++ in other files and link the  object files together.

Comment: **M.M** thank you. I except what you sugest and I will do this, but I want to underestand the issue described above.

Comment: @ApterRostislav What Nathan Oliver meant was that having `const int arr[] = {...};` you cant do `const int foo[] = arr;` in C++. But you can use pointers with no problem.

Comment: That is exactly the problem. In my case, `stm->dev` is pointer to `const type_name`. So it should be ok if I do `stm->dev = devices;`, but: when I link this code with GCC - OK, when I link with G++ - linker fails.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190919/mixing-extern-and-const)

> Um, since const s are implicitly static, you need an extern even on the a_global_var definition (in file.c). Without this, anything that includes file.h will not link because it is looking for a const int a_global_var with external linkage.

Or

> You can use them together (`extern` and `const`). But you need to be consistent on your use of const because when C++ does name decoration, const is included in the type information that is used to decorate the symbol names. so extern const int i will refer to a different variable than extern int i
>   Unless you use extern "C" {}. C name decoration doesn't pay attention to const.